# group messages by same users

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables .. 1- users,,2-messages

I wrote this query but it doesn't show the last subject and I need last subject

```
select (
        CASE WHEN messages.sender = 68314 THEN messages.receiver ELSE messages.sender END
        ) AS user_id, 
        MAX(messages.added) last_added,messages.subject,
        MAX(messages.id) as last_id,users.username  
FROM messages  
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = IF(messages.sender = 68314, messages.receiver, messages.sender) 
WHERE (messages.sender = 68314 or messages.receiver = 68314) AND messages.sender!=0  
GROUP BY 
(
    CASE WHEN messages.sender = 68314 THEN messages.receiver ELSE messages.sender END
) 
ORDER BY last_added DESC
```

It shows first subject, not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

please give this query a try.  It first select max(id) of messages of people talking to id 68314 assuming those are created last...and joins back with messages, and the joined with users to get the other person's name.

```
SELECT last_messages.user_id,
       m.added as last_added,
       m.subject,
       last_messages.last_id,
       u.username
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT IF(sender = 68314,receiver,sender) as user_id,
         MAX(id) as last_id
  FROM messages
  WHERE IF(sender = 68314,sender,receiver) = 68314
  GROUP BY user_id
  )last_messages
  ON last_messages.last_id = m.id
INNER JOIN users u ON last_messages.user_id = u.id
ORDER by last_added;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36f39/6)